# Algorithm to merge tagged intervals

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I have a set of `Items`, each one has both `Start` and `End`

```
class Item
{
   int Value { get; }
   DateTimeOffset Start { get; }
   DateTimeOffset End { get; }
}
```

For example:

- **1**: 2019/01/01 => 2019/12/31
- **2**: 2020/01/01 => 2020/12/31

So there are 2 non-overlapping intervals. Value **1** covers all the year 2019, and the value **2** covers all the year 2020.

But suddenly, I realize that I forgot a value in-between.

- **3**: 2019/06/01 => 2019/08/01

So I think of doing some kind of "import" operation with the values I forgot.

The result of it should be:

- **1**: 2019/01/31 => 2019/05/31
- **3**: 2019/06/01 => 2019/08/01
- **1**: 2019/08/02 => 2019/12/31
- **2**: 2020/01/01 => 2020/12/31

As you see, the value **3** is inserted and reconciled with the existing values. It should be "merged" and the existing intervals are modified so they none of them overlap.

I don't have a clue of how to do this "import" that generates the resulting items.

Comment: How far have you got?  Can you show the code of your attempt to solve this, or give us an idea of where you're running into issues?

Comment: How do you determine the priority of which value to use?
Say, if you had {1, 2020-01-01, 2020-01-31} and {2, 2020-01-01, 2020-01-31}, which value should be used?

Comment: Compute the union of all intervals (which results in a disjoint union of intervals in general) and partition it with the set of end-points of the input.

Comment: @Xtros The imported values have priority over the existing ones.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Could you, please, illustrate the algorithm with an example? I still don't understand you :(

Comment: You can re-model the data a little bit differently: {Date, IsState|IsEnd, Value}. With each import, the list just need to simply be re-ordered by Date and then apply the merging rules.

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension method. I assume that list is sorted by start date.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Start { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset End { get; set; }
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Item> WithUpdate(this IEnumerable<Item> enumerable)
    {
        using (var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
        {
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            Item previous, current=null;
            previous = (Item)enumerator.Current;
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                current = (Item)enumerator.Current;
                if (previous.End >= current.Start)
                {
                    previous.End = ((Item)enumerator.Current).Start.AddDays(-1);
                }
                yield return previous;
                previous = (Item)enumerator.Current;
            }
            yield return current;
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        List<Item> list = new List<Item>() {
            new Item() { Value = 1, Start = DateTime.Now, End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10) },
            new Item() { Value = 2, Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(8), End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15) },
            new Item() { Value = 3, Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(12), End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(20) }
        };

        foreach (Item item in list) {
            Console.WriteLine("Star ={0},End={1}", item.Start.ToString(), item.End.ToString());
        }

        foreach (Item item in list.WithUpdate())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Star ={0},End={1}", item.Start.ToString(), item.End.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
        //Item item = new Item() { Value = 1, Start = DateTime.Now, End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10) };
    }
```

Comment: Can you please check the code? I've tried it and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Please check it now I have attached the calling procedure